A Tool to Load/Unload aliases and functions when cd'ing?
Does anyone know a tool (not a script) that automatically loads shell aliases and functions when I cd into a directory and unloads them when I leave?
By unloading, I mean restoring what got overwritten and removing what got created by the load.
In practice I'd put my custom aliases and functions into a .envrc (shell) file into the root of my projects.
I know there are tools that can achieve this with some hacks, but I would like to avoid those hacks and just have a .envrc file if possible.
Would you use such a tool or the existing solutions are good enough?
I'm asking it because I started building something that solves the above.
My research regarding existing solutions:
Direnv

Fast, supports many shells
Does not support aliases or functions out of the box
It can work with some hack from a 10y old still open issue: https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/73

Quickenv

Replacement/extension for Direnv

SmartCD

Supports Bash and Zsh
It provides running scripts when entering or leaving a directory
It provides stashing and auto unstashing variables, aliases, and functions
It can work if you set up the enter and exit scripts
Last commit 6 years ago

Autoenv, ondir

Similar to SmartCD but without the stashing and auto unstashing features

zsh-autoenv

Supports only Zsh
It includes stashing from SmartCD
Auto unstashing is called at exit, but buggy when unloading nested envs
It can work if you stash what you define in the enter script

Shadowenv

Supports Bash, Zsh, Fish
Uses the Shadowlisp syntax for the env files

They say "The intention isn't really for users to write these files directly"


Not really a good fit

